# Best way to avoid "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

I have a code below, how should I avoid Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when I'm on the next page and the element is not in the HTML for that page.

```
const cokiesButton = document.querySelector(".cookies__button");
loadEventListeners();
function loadEventListeners() {
 cokiesButton.addEventListener('click', addLocal);
}
function addLocal(){
 cookies.classList.add("animate-out"); 
}
```

Should I do something like this?

```
if(cokiesButton){
 cokiesButton.addEventListener('click', addLocal);
}
```

but that does not seem like a good solution to keep wrapping all these events inside an if statement.

any ideas of something better than this?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should do. Otherwise, you can restructure your code so that you're not running javascript on the "next page" which is meant for the other page

Comment: cokies? Then cookies?

Comment: Don't call `addEventListener` on `null`.

Comment: @AnilRedshift but jquery events do not have that? as I've never noticed it. what you think should be a solution when there are a lot of events that need to be wrapped into an if?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the if-statement is the *&&* operator. In other words, you could also do this:

```
cokiesButton && cokiesButton.addEventListener('click', addLocal);
```

The right hand side is only executed if the left hand side is not false. **But I should remember that this is a bit harder to understand than the if-statement, so you should use it judiciously.**

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an old method I use from the old days of es5. Could be a use for you if you do not really care to know when a method assign fails. Hope it helps

```
function getUnSafe(val, alt) {
    /* returns alt if empty string or null or undefined, else the value
     * works good for undefined props of existing obj */
    if (val === false || val === 0) return val;
    if (!val || /^\s*$/.test(val)) return alt;
    return val;
}   
var dummy = {
    addEventListener:function(){}
};
getUnSafe(document.querySelector(".cookies__button"), dummy).addEventListener('click', addLocal);
```

Comment: Why not just `return (val === 0 || val) ? val : alt`

Comment: @JonasW the method was covering for a group of scenarios I needed.. Sure anyone can change it to meet his needs

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

```
function addLocal(){
 cookies.classList.add("animate-out"); 
}

function onClick(query, listener) {
  const cookiesButton = document.querySelector(query);
  if (!cookiesButton) {
    return;
  }
  cookiesButton.addEventListener('click', listener);

  // in case you want to do some chaining
  return cookiesButton;
}

onClick('.cookies__button_1', addLocal);
onClick('.cookies__button_2', addLocal);
onClick('.cookies__button_3', addLocal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
   // ... Your code
 } catch(e) {
   console.log("You can safely ignore this:", e);
  // Failure is always an option. But lets just ignore it
 }
```

While that certainly works, it would be better to only include the code on pages were it is needed / works.

Comment: This is even worse than the OP's suggestion because any failure will no longer be seen, especially unintentional ones.

Comment: They do happen but in that case it is still apropriate to keep the page running instead of crashing everythig